# How to move the legend in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts, draggable, legend

the legend placement of the Highcharts library is not really intelligent, so I'd like to offer the user the possibility to drag the legend as he likes. It seems that in principle that could be done via

```
jQuery(".highcharts-legend").draggable();
```

But it seems that "It doesn't work because jQuery draggable bases on position absolute and top/left css values and highcharts draw chart inside SVG namespace - position absolute or top/left css attribute doesn't work there" ([source](http://dev.highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=7967&p=37347)).

Does anyone know nevertheless a solution?

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This suggestions is requested, so you can vote for it here: http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/912335-draggable-legend-box

Comment: The solution from Torstein Hønsi works pretty well. Thanks for that!

Comment: NOTE: If the legend gets modified after the init the legend is no longer draggable when using the draggable-legend-box.js